# private variable inside fragment are all null, why?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have of null object inside a fragment. The basic idea is that I have an activity that fetches a database asynchronously. However my recyclerview where I will populate the data lives into a fragment. The pseudo-code is more or less

ACTIVITY:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //kicks off a query to the server
    mData = new Gson().fromJson(getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constants.MYDATA), MyData.class);
    if (mVenue == null) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    // a bunch of stuff
    // create a fragment
    mMyFrag = new MyFrag();
}

public void CallBackWhenDone(final List<DataSet> dataset) {

    // notify the frag that we are done
    mMyFrag.notifyDataSetChanged(messages);
}
```

FRAGMENT:

```
private RecyclerView mRV;
private ParentActivity mActivity;
private ActivityAsynchData mAsynchData;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler, container, false);
mRV = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
mRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    if (null != mActivity) {
        mAsynchData = mActivity.GetAsynchData();
    }

    if (null != mAsynchData) {
        mRV.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), mAsynchData));
    }
}

// mRV is null when the activity "CallBackWhenDone" calls the frag
// all private variables are gone! why?
public void notifyDataSetChanged(final List<Message> messages) {
    MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = ((MyRecyclerAdapter) mRV.getAdapter());
    adapter.setMessageList(messages);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I ended up hacking my recycler (mRV in this case) view to be static, but this looks super hacked.

any way around? In other words how can I fetch my "mRV" after the fragment has been created and the private vars are all gone.

Comment: Use a bus library like Otto or EventBus. Much easier to maintain and no need to attach/detach listeners from configuration changes.

Comment: which private variable inside fragment are null?

Comment: mRV is null if I pass data to the fragment from the activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What i could understand is, that you initialised the fragment and try to access the recycler view in that but its throwing you null. I am not surprised to see it being as null. The way you have called the method is not correct.You need to get the hosted and already running fragment, instance  try doing this:

if you are using support fragment use `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`.

```
MyFrag fragment = (MyFrag) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentHolder);
fragment.<specific_function_name>();
```

Here , the `R.id.fragmentHolder` is the id of the frame layout or any layout that you are using to host your fragment inside the an activity.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Are you calling this from the activity? The recyclerview lives in the fragment. I need to get a hold of the recyclerview pointer inside the fragment code after the fragment code has been initialized.

Comment: Yes this need to be called inside the activity which is holding the fragment.